# Check the value of character variable

Tags: c, arduino

I'm writing some code for Arduino and I'm not sure if I'm checking the value of this character variable correctly. Can you please tell me if this is correct:

```
const char* front = "front";
const char* back = "back";

eyeballs(front);
eyeballs(back);

void eyeballs(const char* frontOrBack){ 

if (frontOrBack == "front") {
    digitalWrite(frontEyes, LOW);}//end if   
  else if (frontOrBack == "back") {
    digitalWrite(backEyes, LOW);}//end else*/
}
```

Comment: change `X == Y` to `!strcmp(X, Y)` . Your code compares if the two strings share the same memory location

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare C-strings. What you do is pointer comparison.

```
if ( strcmp(frontOrBack, "front") == 0 ) {
   digitalWrite(frontEyes, LOW);}//end if   
  else if ( strcmp(frontOrBack, "back") == 0 ) {
    digitalWrite(backEyes, LOW);}//end else*/
}
```

In this comparison,

```
if (frontOrBack == "front") {
```

the pointer value `frontOrBack` is compared with the address of the string literal `"front"` (in an expression, a string literal gets converted to a pointer to its first element).